# How to setup wireless AP with two wifi cards and ethernet as WAN on debian?

Tags: debian, wifi, dhcp, bridge

I'm trying to build wireless AP with 2 Atheros cards (AR5413 / AR5414 both), and one ethernet card to act as WAN. I am also having doubts if I should use `ath5k` or `madwifi` drivers. I've tried both already but none worked as I wanted

Here is what I want (if possible):

1. wireless cards (`wlan0` / `wlan1`) in ap/master mode
2. wpa2 encryption on both interfaces
3. each wireless interface has static IP (ex: `10.0.1.1` for `wlan0`, and `10.0.2.1` for `wlan1`)
4. each wireless interface has dhcp-server for managing client's addresses
   (ex: pool for `wlan0`: `10.0.1.100-10.0.1.120`, pool for `wlan0`: `10.0.2.100 - 10.0.2.120`)
5. `eth0` should be WAN interface with dhcp-client (public ip)
6. forward traffic (and internet) from WAN to wireless interfaces (not sure how this should be done... `iptables+dnsmasq`?)
7. `QoS` control (optional)

I've tried and managed to get wireless `essid` on box using `hostapd` (with `WPA2` working), but it requires bridge (`br0`) interface to work (not sure how). This bridge forces ethernet and wireless card **not** to have IP addresses and bridge takes public IP from cable modem via `eth0`. As I try to connect my wireless ESSID my client machine (cell phone for ex.) can't get IP (no dhcp-server) and I don't know what configuration to put addresses manually because there is no local IP on `wlan0` interface itself.

Just to recap:

```
[INTERNET] <---- eth0(WAN) <----?NAT?----> wlan0/wlan1
```

Any suggestion is welcome (due concept or implementation).

Comment: This is surely doable with a Debian installation, I have done this in the past. But consider using [pfSense](pfsense.org), which is based on FreeBSD and has a nice GUI and is much simpler to set up than doing everything from scratch. And BTW, for two distinct WLANs you don't necessarily need two network adapters, many Atheros chips allow multiple networks (up to 5?) on a single chip.

Comment: Related: [How to turn my Linux netbook into WiFi AP](http://superuser.com/a/437229/105023)

Comment: Thank you for quick replay @Marco. I've never used BSD before, but I'll try pfSence (hope it has similar CLI syntax as GNU/Linux). I wanted to this with debian in first place. I've been reading pfSence forum and there is buncha useful info(like there is codex that everything should be exlained in details). Thanx again for the tip.

Comment: wlan0 is on-board, so I think you are asking about wlan1 and wlan2 if they are both external USB adapters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to create one or 2 APs using 2 wifi card and one ethernet interface

Install the `hostapd` package and the [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) tool :

```
sudo apt install hostapd
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
sudo make install
```

Create the first AP : AP1

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAP1 MyPassPhrase1
```

Create the second AP : AP2

```
create_ap wlan1 eth0 MyAP2 MyPassPhrase2
```

You can specify the driver `--driver ath5k` as motioned by the create_ap developper's.

Next step you should edit your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`  to bind a MAC address to a specific IP address. Add the following line

```
#The `wlan0`:

dhcp-host:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,10.0.1.1

#The dhcp range :

interface=wlan0
except-interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=10.0.1.100,10.0.1.120

#The `wlan1`:

dhcp-host:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,10.0.2.1
#The dhcp range :

interface=wlan1
except-interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.2.100,10.0.2.120
```

Change the `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` with the MAC adress of your `wlan0` and `wlan1`

Answer (score 1):

Possible and IMO easiest solution for the router:

> [INTERNET] ppp0 <--- NAT --> br0 <-- --> wlan0/1

`br0` has an assigned local IP, and wlan0,wlan1 are managed by bridge. You can add them with `post-up brctl addif br0 wlan0` for `wlan0`.

So, you need to edit your /etc/network/interfaces for ppp0, br0, wlan0, wlan1.
After ppp0 (or whatever you have) is up apply these

> echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
>   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -s 10.0.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

But! For production environment you need a good firewall.